# Python 3 Generator Function Returning the Same Value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, debugging, generator, yield

I'm trying to build a batch generator which takes a large Pandas DataFrame as input and output as a given number of rows (batch_size). I practiced on the smaller dataframe with 10 rows to get it work. I have trouble with the generator function where the for loop below works well on the practice dataframe, and spits out the designated batch size:

```
for i in range(0, len(df), 3):
lower = i
upper = i+3
print(df.iloc[lower:upper])
```

However, trying to build this into a generator function is proving difficult:

```
def Generator(batch_size, seed = None):
num_items = len(df)
x = df.sample(frac = 1, replace = False, random_state = seed)
for offset in range(0, num_items, batch_size):
    lower_limit = offset
    upper_limit = offset+batch_size
    batch = x.iloc[lower_limit:upper_limit]
    yield batch
```

Unfortunately:

```
next(Generator(e.g.1))
```

returns the same row over and over again

I'm fairly new to working with this, and I feel I must be missing something, however, I can't spot what.
If anyone could point out what might be the issue I would very much appreciate it.

Edit:
The dataframe is predefined, it is:

```
raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy', 'Sarah', 'Gueniva', 'Know', 'Sara', 'Cat'], 
    'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze', 'Mornig', 'Jaker', 'Alom', 'Ormon', 'Koozer'], 
    'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73, 53, 26, 72, 73, 24], 
    'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 13, 52, 72, 26, 26],
    'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 82, 52, 56, 234, 254]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
df
```

Comment: You never provide the `df` to your generator function?

Comment: Hi, the df is predefined as df before the generator is run and so it does not need to be specified to the Generator() function. I've added the df for you to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an iterator on the result of calling your Generator and `next()` that iterator. Else you recreate new Generator "states" for the generator which might have the same "first line" if you provide a seed.

After fixing the indentation problems it works as it should:

```
import pandas as pd

# I dislike variable scope bleeding into the function, provide df explicitly
def Generator(df, batch_size, seed = None):
    num_items = len(df)
    x = df.sample(frac = 1, replace = False, random_state = seed)
    for offset in range(0, num_items, batch_size):
        lower_limit = offset
        upper_limit = offset+batch_size
        batch = x.iloc[lower_limit:upper_limit]
        yield batch


raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy', 'Sarah', 
                           'Gueniva', 'Know', 'Sara', 'Cat'], 
    'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze', 'Mornig', 
                  'Jaker', 'Alom', 'Ormon', 'Koozer'], 
    'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73, 53, 26, 72, 73, 24], 
    'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 13, 52, 72, 26, 26],
    'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70, 82, 52, 56, 234, 254]}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 
                                       'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])


# capture a "state" for the generator function
i = iter(Generator(df, 2)) 

# get the next states from the iterator and print
print(next(i))
print(next(i))
print(next(i))
```

Output:

```
  first_name last_name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore
8       Sara     Ormon   73            26            234
6    Gueniva     Jaker   26            52             52


  first_name last_name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore
5      Sarah    Mornig   53            13             82
9        Cat    Koozer   24            26            254

  first_name last_name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore
1      Molly  Jacobson   52            24             94
2       Tina       Ali   36            31             57
```

Alternativly you can do:

```
k = Generator(df, 1)
print(next(k))
print(next(k))
print(next(k))
```

wich works as well.

If you do

```
print(next(Generator(df, 2)))    
print(next(Generator(df, 2)))
print(next(Generator(df, 2)))
```

You create three seperate shuffled df`s that might have the same line shown to you because you only ever print the first "iteration" of it and then it gets discarded